# Cut html input while preserving tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I need to cut html input to a certain length while still preserving tags. The total length **must include the html tags**. I am unable to find a solution that includes the html tag length in the final length. How can I cut html input to a certain length without breaking the tags and making sure that all opening tags have a closing?

Basically, I am getting html input from a user and I need to make it fit within a certain length. To do this, I do not want to break any of the html tags but I need to make sure that the total length (including tags) is less than the maximum.

For example, cutting this string to 20 characters:

```
<p>this is an example</p>
```

should give an output of

```
<p>this is an ex</p>
```

And this cut to 50 chars

```
<p>this <a href="http://example.com">click me</a>jiasd</p>
```

Should give

```
<p>this <a href="http://example.com">click</a></p>
```

I have tried this solution and it works well for cutting the text to a certain length, but I cannot find a way to get it to count tag length in the total:

```
function truncateHtml($text, $length = 100, $ending = '...', $exact = false, $considerHtml = true) {
    if ($considerHtml) {
        // if the plain text is shorter than the maximum length, return the whole text
        if (strlen(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $text)) <= $length) {
            return $text;
        }
        // splits all html-tags to scanable lines
        preg_match_all('/(<.+?>)?([^<>]*)/s', $text, $lines, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $total_length = strlen($ending);
        $open_tags = array();
        $truncate = '';
        foreach ($lines as $line_matchings) {
            // if there is any html-tag in this line, handle it and add it (uncounted) to the output
            if (!empty($line_matchings[1])) {
                // if it's an "empty element" with or without xhtml-conform closing slash
                if (preg_match('/^<(\s*.+?\/\s*|\s*(img|br|input|hr|area|base|basefont|col|frame|isindex|link|meta|param)(\s.+?)?)>$/is', $line_matchings[1])) {
                    // do nothing
                // if tag is a closing tag
                } else if (preg_match('/^<\s*\/([^\s]+?)\s*>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) {
                    // delete tag from $open_tags list
                    $pos = array_search($tag_matchings[1], $open_tags);
                    if ($pos !== false) {
                    unset($open_tags[$pos]);
                    }
                // if tag is an opening tag
                } else if (preg_match('/^<\s*([^\s>!]+).*?>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) {
                    // add tag to the beginning of $open_tags list
                    array_unshift($open_tags, strtolower($tag_matchings[1]));
                }
                // add html-tag to $truncate'd text
                $truncate .= $line_matchings[1];
            }
            // calculate the length of the plain text part of the line; handle entities as one character
            $content_length = strlen(preg_replace('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', ' ', $line_matchings[2]));
            if ($total_length+$content_length> $length) {
                // the number of characters which are left
                $left = $length - $total_length;
                $entities_length = 0;
                // search for html entities
                if (preg_match_all('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', $line_matchings[2], $entities, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                    // calculate the real length of all entities in the legal range
                    foreach ($entities[0] as $entity) {
                        if ($entity[1]+1-$entities_length <= $left) {
                            $left--;
                            $entities_length += strlen($entity[0]);
                        } else {
                            // no more characters left
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $truncate .= substr($line_matchings[2], 0, $left+$entities_length);
                // maximum lenght is reached, so get off the loop
                break;
            } else {
                $truncate .= $line_matchings[2];
                $total_length += $content_length;
            }
            // if the maximum length is reached, get off the loop
            if($total_length>= $length) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (strlen($text) <= $length) {
            return $text;
        } else {
            $truncate = substr($text, 0, $length - strlen($ending));
        }
    }
    // if the words shouldn't be cut in the middle...
    if (!$exact) {
        // ...search the last occurance of a space...
        $spacepos = strrpos($truncate, ' ');
        if (isset($spacepos)) {
            // ...and cut the text in this position
            $truncate = substr($truncate, 0, $spacepos);
        }
    }
    // add the defined ending to the text
    $truncate .= $ending;
    if($considerHtml) {
        // close all unclosed html-tags
        foreach ($open_tags as $tag) {
            $truncate .= '</' . $tag . '>';
        }
    }
    return $truncate;
}
```

Comment: Do you have that `this is an example` in a variable?

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: If you put a bounty on it… still … please explain what you have _tried_. This is not a bounty-code exchange site...

Comment: I think you're probably [asking the wrong question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you'll elaborate on what you're actually trying to do, maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I have elaborated more on what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is the desired output of `truncateHtml("<div><span>Hello</span>Beautiful<span>World</span></div>",50);`?

Comment: @TecBrat `<div><span>Hello</span>Beautiful</div>`

Comment: What should this  `<p><a href="http://example.com" class="anchor" id="test" title="test">test</a></p>` change to with limitation of 20 characters?

Comment: It looks like you alter the html by cutting some tags. That's the reason this won't really work. Otherwise build up an array of tag locations (begin/end). With that info you have all the math you need to not only count tags/text length but to create a new html with that info. Use this to find tags `<(?:(?:/?\w+\s*/?)|(?:\w+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

Comment: This very sarcastic yet popular answer that some would rather we not link, encourages us to find a solution that does not involve parsing HTML with Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @TechBrat what solution would you suggest that does not involve regex?

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/antonzaytsev/1260890

Comment: That's the same code that I specifically said *does not work*.

Comment: I think the accepted answer manages to help without allowing his un̨ho͞ly radiańcé to destro҉y all enli̍̈́̂̈́ghtenment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Regular Expressions, it is not easily possible to memorize length and occurrences while traversing characters so you may follow a solution combined with **RegEx** and **DOM** (this workaround is mostly done by the help of DOM).

The whole philosophy is this:

1- If last node is a [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) or [DOMText](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php):

- If by removing this node, total length will be greater than limit ->
  remove it.
- If by removing this node, total length will be less than limit ->
  truncate.
- Total length > limit ? Recurs (1) : Return result.

```
function truncateHTML($html, $limit = 20) {
    static $wrapper = null;
    static $wrapperLength = 0;

    // trim unwanted CR/LF characters
    $html = trim($html);

    // Remove HTML comments
    $html = preg_replace("~<!--.*?-->~", '', $html);

    // If $html in in plain text
    if ((strlen(strip_tags($html)) > 0) && strlen(strip_tags($html)) == strlen($html))  {
        return substr($html, 0, $limit);
    }
    // If $html doesn't have a root element
    elseif (is_null($wrapper)) {
        if (!preg_match("~^\s*<[^\s!?]~", $html)) {
            // Defining a tag as our HTML wrapper
            $wrapper = 'div';
            $htmlWrapper = "<$wrapper></$wrapper>";
            $wrapperLength = strlen($htmlWrapper);
            $html = preg_replace("~><~", ">$html<", $htmlWrapper);
        }
    }

    // Calculating total length
    $totalLength = strlen($html);

    // If our input length is less than limit, we are done.
    if ($totalLength <= $limit) {
        if ($wrapper) {
            return preg_replace("~^<$wrapper>|</$wrapper>$~", "", $html);
        }
        return strlen(strip_tags($html)) > 0 ? $html : '';
    }

    // Initializing a DOM object to hold our HTML
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html,  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED  | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    // Initializing a DOMXPath object to query on our DOM
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // Query last node (this does not include comment or text nodes)
    $lastNode = $xpath->query("./*[last()]")->item(0);

    // While manipulating, when there is no HTML element left
    if ($totalLength > $limit && is_null($lastNode)) {
        if (strlen(strip_tags($html)) >= $limit) {
            $textNode = $xpath->query("//text()")->item(0);
            if ($wrapper) {
                $textNode->nodeValue = substr($textNode->nodeValue, 0, $limit );
                $html = $dom->saveHTML();
                return preg_replace("~^<$wrapper>|</$wrapper>$~", "", $html);
            } else {
                $lengthAllowed = $limit - ($totalLength - strlen($textNode->nodeValue));
                if ($lengthAllowed <= 0) {
                    return '';
                }
                $textNode->nodeValue = substr($textNode->nodeValue, 0, $lengthAllowed);
                $html = $dom->saveHTML();
                return strlen(strip_tags($html)) > 0 ? $html : '';
            }
        } else {
            $textNode = $xpath->query("//text()")->item(0);
            $textNode->nodeValue = substr($textNode->nodeValue, 0, -(($totalLength - ($wrapperLength > 0 ? $wrapperLength : 0)) - $limit));
            $html = $dom->saveHTML();
            return strlen(strip_tags($html)) > 0 ? $html : '';
        }
    }
    // If we have a text node after our last HTML element
    elseif ($nextNode = $lastNode->nextSibling) {
        if ($nextNode->nodeType === 3 /* DOMText */) {
            $nodeLength = strlen($nextNode->nodeValue);
            // If by removing our text node total length will be greater than limit
            if (($totalLength - ($wrapperLength > 0 ? $wrapperLength : 0)) - $nodeLength >= $limit) {
                // We should remove it
                $nextNode->parentNode->removeChild($nextNode);
                $html = $dom->saveHTML();
                return truncateHTML($html, $limit);
            }
            // If by removing our text node total length will be less than limit
            else {
                // We should truncate our text to fit the limit
                $nextNode->nodeValue = substr($nextNode->nodeValue, 0, ($limit - (($totalLength - ($wrapperLength > 0 ? $wrapperLength : 0)) - $nodeLength)));
                $html = $dom->saveHTML();
                // Caring about custom wrapper
                if ($wrapper) {
                    return preg_replace("~^<$wrapper>|</$wrapper>$~", "", $html);
                }
                return $html;
            } 
        }
    }
    // If current node is an HTML element 
    elseif ($lastNode->nodeType === 1 /* DOMElement */) {
        $nodeLength = strlen($lastNode->nodeValue);
        // If by removing current HTML element total length will be greater than limit
        if (($totalLength - ($wrapperLength > 0 ? $wrapperLength : 0)) - $nodeLength >= $limit) {
            // We should remove it
            $lastNode->parentNode->removeChild($lastNode);
            $html = $dom->saveHTML();
            return truncateHTML($html, $limit);
        }
        // If by removing current HTML element total length will be less than limit
        else {
            // We should truncate our node value to fit the limit
            $lastNode->nodeValue = substr($lastNode->nodeValue, 0, ($limit - (($totalLength - ($wrapperLength > 0 ? $wrapperLength : 0)) - $nodeLength)));
            $html = $dom->saveHTML();
            if ($wrapper) {
                return preg_replace("~^<$wrapper>|</$wrapper>$~", "", $html);
            }
            return $html;
        }
    }
}
```

### Examples

**1-** Giving an input like below with `$limit = 16`:

```
<div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span>test<p> something</p><span>letter</span></div>
```

Will result into an HTML which is illustrated step by step here:

```
Step 0: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span>test<p> something</p><span>letter</span></div>
Step 1: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span>test<p> something</p></div>
Step 2: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span>test</div>
Step 3: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span></div>
Step 4: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was </div>
Step 5: <div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span></div>
Step 6: <div>some data from </div>
Step 7: <div>some </div>
```

**2-** On your own example, this input with `$limit = 50`:

```
<p>this <a href="http://example.com">click me</a>jiasd</p>
```

Will output expected HTML:

```
<p>this <a href="http://example.com">click</a></p>
```

**3-** Plain texts are treated the same (`$limit = 10`):

```
Hi how are you doing?
```

Output:

```
Hi how are
```

**4-** HTML comments included (`$limit = 10`):

```
<div>some data from <span class="first">blahblah test</span> was <span class="second">good</span>test<p> something</p><span class="text">hola</span><!-- comment --></div>
```

Output:

```
string(0) ""
```

Why empty? Because when function hits last but one step it sees `<div></div>` which has a length of `11`. We can't do anything with it so we remove it totally.

**5-** Output of last example with `$limit = 12`:

```
<div>s</div>
```

[**PHP live demo**](https://3v4l.org/FONf5)

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should extract the HTML tags from the truncated string. Then count those characters and truncate the text-only part of the string again.

Please note that the following regex matches all html tags with all attributes (both opening and closing tags).

Before the ending `return $truncate;`:

```
preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>/', $truncate, $html_tags);
$html_tags_length = strlen(implode('', $html_tags));
```

At this point, you can either extract the text part of the string and cut it off, or call your function recursively.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit heuristic, but it should work.

```
function truncateHtml($text, $length = 100) {
    $current_size = strlen($text);
    $diff = strlen($text);
    $remainder = $current_size - $length;
    while($diff > 0 AND $remainder > 0) {
        $pattern = "/(.*)[^<>](?=<)/s";
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $text);
        $diff = $current_size - strlen($text);
        $current_size = strlen($text);
        $remainder = $current_size - $length;
    }
// iff $diff == 0 there are no more characters to remove
// iff $remainder == 0 there should removed no more characters
    return $text;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/mFuASx) the running code.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement it splitting by regular expression and counting only characters that are not part of tags.

Example:

```
<?php

function htmlTrim($inStr, $length) {
    $c = 0;
    $outStr =  preg_replace_callback(
        "/<.*?>|[^<>]*/",
        function($str) use (& $c, $length){
            $str = $str[0];
            if ($str && $str[0] == "<") { // Is tag.
                return $str;
            } else {
                if ($c >= $length) return ""; // Lenght already exceeded.
                $l = strlen($str);
                $c += $l;
                $overflow = $c - $length;
                if ($overflow > 0) {
                    return substr($str, 0,  $l - $overflow);
                } else {
                    return $str;
                }
            };
        },
        $inStr
    );

    return $outStr;
};

echo htmlTrim("<span>Hello <b>World foobar</b></span>", 11);
```

Comment: I want to count characters that are part of tags. Your current example prints `<span>Hello <b>World</b></span>`, but what I am asking for should print `<span>He</span>` with that same initial string trimmed to a length of 15. Because there is no room for the span tags if cut to 11 characters, it should return a blank string.

Comment: Sorry. I missunderstood you. But, in fact, you can achieve it by the same principle except for that you must store all chunks into an array to be able to take closing tags in account (you cannot rely on open tag length +1 because they can contain attributes and/or extra spaces). But, anyway, what you are trying to do is basically an xml parser. There is a lot of libraries that implement it and, if you want to avoid complex user inputs to break your parser, the best solution should be to use one of that.

Comment: ...also, you need to handle whole tag removals (to avoid wasting characters in emptied tags. I.e.: "<p>hello <b></b></p>"). But the most important thing: If html is user input, you should take care not only on not to break it but also don't accept (or dynamically fix) already broken html inputs. So, again, I recommend you to rely on existing xml parsing library like expat (the best I used). I think php provides its own functions too, but I never tried them.